# NullReferenceException on launch (unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

[boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hiznu.png)
[console]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhv8h.png

I get this error every time and cannot do anything.
I have tried closing, restarting pc and reinstalling

Comment: And what details does it give in the console. You clearly have some project.

Comment: i have added a photo

Comment: So doesnt like people posting pictures of errors or code because its not searchable.  And the error message seems pretty clear  as to whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

That is an access token expiration error. They just didn't handle the exception. It happened to me once.

Close the Editor, sign out from Unity Hub, sign back in and start the Editor.